# Add assets folder in mern io

Tags: mern

i am using mern.io my web pack config is looks like :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
var postcssFocus = require('postcss-focus');
var postcssReporter = require('postcss-reporter');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  entry: {
    app: [
      'eventsource-polyfill',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './client/index.js',
    ],
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: 'http://0.0.0.0:8888/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      'client',
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader',
      }
      , {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/ ,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }

      , {
        test: /\.jsx*$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.+\.config.js/],
        loader: 'babel',
      }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      }, {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=1&minetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=1&minetype=application/font-woff" },


      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=1' }
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity,
      filename: 'vendor.js',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        CLIENT: JSON.stringify(true),
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      }
    }),
  ],

  postcss: () => [
    postcssFocus(),
    cssnext({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'IE > 10'],
    }),
    postcssReporter({
      clearMessages: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

i would like to add a custom css file which resides in : /public/assets/css/custom.css; Then what would be my configurations?

i can import css file in node_modules  eg : require('rc-slider/assets/index.css');

as it says in the config :

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/ ,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
```

i have replicated the entry  with :

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /public/ ,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
```

but not working

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approach to handle this situation.

1.
You can use the following to add public folder to serve static files.
app.use(express.static('public'));

And then you can add the file in the html if you are using server side rendering.

2.

You can put this file on client side and simply import the file at the entry point of webpack on client side.
And webpack will automatically include it using style loader.